# Groovy: what is wrong with the`{}` in array?

Tags: groovy

```
def hosts = [{}, {}]
hosts[0].id = 111
hosts[1].id = 222
println hosts[0].id
println hosts[1].id
```

I expect the result to be:

```
111
222
```

But the actual result is

```
222
```

You can run this in https://groovyide.com/playground

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{}` is an "empty" (no-op, single-arity) closure and not an empty map (like e.g. in JS).

Use the literal for an empty map instead: `[:]`; e.g.

```
def hosts = [[:], [:]]
hosts[0].id = 111
hosts[1].id = 222
println hosts[0].id
println hosts[1].id
```

So why does setting a property on two different closures end up changing
both closures to hold the same value?  Setting a property on a closure
is changing the `Binding` of the closure.  And since both closures are
in the same scope they both share the same binding.  Ergo the second
`id=222` assignment overrides the first one.

```
def hosts = [{}, {}]
println hosts*.binding
// → [groovy.lang.Binding@56f2bbea, groovy.lang.Binding@56f2bbea]
```

Comment: thank you, seems `{}` has special meaning in Groovy, this is really anti-intuitive.

Comment: no, it's not. `[]` is a list-literal, `[:]` is a map-literal, `{}` is a Closure or block definition

Comment: Thanks, finally I got the reason.